# Testlink installation issue

Tags: testlink

Hello I have an issue to install testlink, I use macOS. I change the data in config.inc.php file for:

$tlCfg->log_path = '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/testlink/logs/';
and
$g_repositoryPath = '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/testlink/upload_area/';

**Result:**
Checking if /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/testlink/gui/templates_c/ directory is writable (by user used to run webserver process)Failed!
Checking if /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/testlink/logs directory is writable (by user used to run webserver process)Failed!
Checking if /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/testlink/upload_area directory is writable (by user used to run webserver process)Failed!
I don't have an idea what is wrong...?
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto testlink -> logs / upload_area -> press Command + I -> in Permission Enable Read Write to Everyone.